# Objective C Collect Data from TextField and List in TextView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ios6

On View1, I have an empty textView that will populate with data from a textField. The textField is on View2. Every time I swipe right to view the data in View1, it never lists in the textView. It overwrites whatever is currently there.

Here's my code: https://github.com/dward1289/Objective-CII/tree/master/week4Proj

The assignment is already done, but even after it was graded I never found out what I was doing wrong. Please take a look, and tell me what I can change so that the textField data will populate in the textView and not overwrite the current text.

Comment: Why don't you ask your tutor what you were doing wrong then?

Comment: You should include the relevant code snippets in your post. The fewest readers want to dig through a whole project.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want to append the new input to the old information
. If so,

```
-(void)DidClose:(NSString*)nameString
{
    txtView.text = [txtView.text stringByAppendingString:nameString];
}
```